# How to get private properties names of a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, private, class-fields

##### Introduction

In order to get the properties of a class instance we can just use the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` method like in the following example

```js
class People {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }    
  getProperties() {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
  }
}
console.log(new People("John", 20).getProperties())
```

This does work because the properties of the object are **public**. But in case the properties of the object are **private** this method doesn't work.

##### Problem

Imagine that you don't want user to modify the `name` and `age` properties *directly* outside a class method, so you make them private.  However, you also want to have a method that makes a copy of an instance in another instance. Since the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` does not work for private properties, you cannot access to the keys in oder to make the `clone()`:

```js
class People {
  #name; #age;
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.#name = name;
    this.#age = age;
  }
  clone(o) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).forEach(key => this[key] = o[key]);
  }
  getName() { return this.#name }
}

p1 = new People("John", 20);
p2 = new People("", 0);

p2.clone(p1);   // Now p2 should have the same properties of p1

console.log(p2.getName());      // Prints "" and should print "John"
```

##### Question

Is there a way to access **private properties names** of a class from inside a class method?

Comment: `getOwnPropertyNames` doesn’t inculde private properties. You have to copy them manually.

Comment: I don't understand the question "*Is there a way to access private properties of a class from inside a class method?*". Sure there is, you demonstrate it in the `getName` class method. And you can also write `copy` as `this.#name = o.#name; this.#age = o.#age`. If you meant to ask about a way to enumerate private properties, please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the suggestion, it's corrected. Yes, what I want is to get an array (or similiar) with the private properties **names**.

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios Sorry to say that is not possible. And while digging around for a reference, I just realised I had answered this question before :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use something called `WeakMaps`. You would do something like this:

```
const _name = new WeakMap();
const _age = new WeakMap();

class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        _name.set(this, name);
        _age.set(this, age);
    }
}
```

As you can see, we use the `set` method to set the value of a weakMap for a specific class.

Now, to access this value in another method, you use the `get` method:

```js
const _name = new WeakMap();
const _age = new WeakMap();

class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        _name.set(this, name);
        _age.set(this, age);
    }

    getName() {
        return _name.get(this);
    }
}

const bob = new Person('Bob', 35); // You will not be able to access the name property by typing "bob.name".
console.log(bob.getName());
```

The `get` method will allow you to access the value of that weakMap for the class mentioned.

For more information about WeakMaps click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

Comment: It's not clear how this has anything at all to do with private instance properties and their names.

Comment: oh, I didn't see the part about private instance properties I just thought normal properties.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know that much about private instance properties, just it looks like weakMaps do the same thing

Comment: Thanks for upvoting anyways.

Comment: still sorry for an answer that doesn't help

Comment: Although is not relate with private keys, maybe if there is a way of making an array of weakmaps I can avoid using private properties

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, it shouldn't be hard

Comment: the only hard part  I see is referencing them in the class itself

Answer (score -1):

Just implement the method returning needed parameters:

```js
getParameters(){
    return { name: this.#name, age: this.#age };
}
```

and use it in the `clone()` method as follows:

```js
clone(o) {
   const { name, age } = o.getParameters();
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
}
```

So you only access object's private parameters by it's methods. If you want a more generic approach, without listing all the parameters, you can use `Object.entries()` method in `getParameters()` method.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that I would have more properties and I want to get them automatically